# React onSubmit will not submit textarea value

Tags: reactjs, forms

I am new to React and can't figure out why my `submitForm` function isn't working. I am mapping through nearby restaurants and returning  5+ places each with a textarea for users to leave a review. Originally, under my `handleChange` function, I only set the value to `e.target.value.` This made what was typed in one textarea appear in all the text areas. So I then rewrote the code in `handleChange` as you see below utilizing a `name` prop. This solved the issue of the value of the textarea acting "globally" but now when I click submit nothing happens.

```
function RestaurantList({
  nearbyRestaurants,
  userReview,
  setUserReview,
  setQuery
}) {
  function handleChange(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUserReview({ ...userReview, [name]: value });
  }

  function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery(userReview);
    setUserReview("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {nearbyRestaurants.map((place) => (
          <div>
            <li>
              <div>{place.name}</div>
              <form onSubmit={submitForm}>
                <input
                  type="text-area"
                  placeholder="Leave a review..."
                  value={userReview.userReview}
                  name={place.name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <button className="submit-button" type="submit">
                  submit
                </button>
              </form>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `<button className="submit-button" type="submit" onClick={submitForm}>submit</button>`

Comment: I just did. The text still won't clear when I submit. However it may have done something. I am sending the `query` value to another component where the reviews will be viewed. When I click that other component I get the following: "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {Denny's}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead" .

Comment: To make the text clear you have to reset userReview.userReview

Comment: @Asutosh Thanks Asutosh. Am I going in the right direction here or way off ?-- under my submitForm function I wrote setUserReview({ userReview: "" }); but nothing clears. I am probably overthinking this :/

Comment: @Asutosh actually that does clear it but it clears all the other textAreas as well. I will get it figured. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah the reason evrything gets cleared is, all the firm's textarea's value points to same userReview object. Try to have separate object/variable for each form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220235/discussion-between-asutosh-and-jon-laboy).